# Channel Entries tag not recognizing passed params

Tags: channel-entries

For some reason my Channel Entries tags aren't recognizing the passed parameters consistently. For example, the below works on the home page but not on any internal pages:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="files" entry_id="12"}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding `dynamic="no"` parameter. Does that fix it?

Comment: upvote for the old classic!

Comment: when in doubt dynamic="no"

Comment: I want to alias dynamic="no" to dynamic="noff"...

Comment: Definitely a dynamic="no" issue.

Comment: I wish `dynamic="no"` was the default. You only ever need it once per template.